# How to export a project game so others can play

Tags: java, export

I have programmed a Sokoban game and when you start it it comes as a java file.
[image]

This is perfect, but I want to export it as a Java file. I have done a lot of research, but all the ways I found did not work.

I want to just send the Java file to my friend so they can play it.

My project structure is:
[image]